# Font used academia

Tags: support, design, user-interface

Can someone tell me what is the font used by academia.SE?

It is very elegant.. Why it is not used throughout the stack exchange network?

Edit:

This is a screenshot of what my browser renders.

[image]

Comment: I added the [tag:design] tag so the design team will see this question. It may take them some time, but hopefully they'll answer it.

Comment: Which font? In the logo or in the text?

Comment: This actually depends on what is available on your computer. You can check the source code for the page to see what fonts _might_ be used, but to see which one actually _is_ used you'll have to cross-reference the list with what is available to your browser, and I don't know of an easy way to do that.

Comment: @eykanal thank you very much!  I added a screenshot of the text I get

Comment: One way to answer questions like these it to use [WhatTheFont!](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/)

Answer (score 4):

For me the font for regular texts is Open Sans, questions in the question list are in Museo Slab – identified with Opera’s and Firefox’s *Inspect Element* tool. I strongly suspect (but cannot verify it right now) that this is loaded as a web font¹, so it should be the same for you, as long as your browser supports web fonts. PS: Looking at your screenshot, it almost certainly is Open Sans.

As to why this is not used all over the network: A font font should match the design, tone and topic of the site. For example, [English Language](https://english.stackexchange.com/) uses a slab-serif font, which I suspect to be a trade-off between readability and feeling a little bit historical (and thus matching the design of that site). Open Sans would not be a good choice for that site in my opinion, as it is too modern. Also, using the same font all over the place eventually gets boring².

---

<sup>¹ [At least one other Stack Exchange uses a web font.](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1443/web-font-varelaround)

² I, for example, have set my browser to auto-replace Arial (and similar) with another font, just because I got so tired of it.</sup>

Comment: Great thank you.. I added a screenshot of the font, is that useful? By the way, what does web font mean exactly?

Comment: @Ant: I edited my answer accordingly. A web font is a font that is directly downloaded by your browser to be used on a web page. For example [this page](http://www.unifraktur.sourceforge.net/) uses a web font to display a font that is most likely not installed on your computer.